# EF - Lost In Migration

Tags: entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

Before the migration I had an 1 to many relationship between tables Work and Factory:

```
public class Work
{
    public int WorkId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Factory> MyFactory { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
public class Factory
{
    public int FactoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Work ParentWork { get; set; }
}
```

Then I tried to change the relationship to be an 1 to 1:

```
public class Work
{
    public int WorkId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Factory MyFactory { get; set; }
}

public class Factory
{
    public int FactoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Work ParentWork { get; set; }
}
```

When I tried to create the migration with:

**add-migration MyMigration**

I received the following error:

**The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Work_dbo.Factory_WorkId". The conflict occurred in database "EntityFrameworkLab.MyContext", table "dbo.Factory", column 'FactoryId'**

Now, I have a few questions:

1) Why couldn't the migration be created, whereas the model is valid?

2) What changes should I implement in the code?

3) If I try to manually revert the changes, the same error message occurs, but this time when I try to do the:

**update-database -verbose**